# Solution group of Pell's equation

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let the *Solution space* of Pell's equation $ x^2-Dy^2 = 1 $ as $ S_D = \{ (x,y) | x^2-Dy^2=1 \} $.

I know the well-defined trivial injection between $ S_\sqrt D $ and $ {\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt D)}^\times $. Let the trivial injection as $ \varphi $, and let the **Solution group** of Pell's equation $ G_\sqrt D = \varphi(S_\sqrt D) $.


Then, What group is isomorphic to $ G_\sqrt D $?


I computed when $D$ is $2$, and got an answer that $ G_\sqrt 2 $ and $ \mathbb{Z} \otimes \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{2\mathbb{Z}} $ are isomorphic.

In general cases, how can compute that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume that $D$ is a squarefree integer, and that $x$ and $y$ are required to be integers. Then this group is the unit group of the ring of integers of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$. [Dirichlet's unit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_unit_theorem) answers your question for the most part.

This theorem tells you that the unit group is a finitely generated abelian group, and its rank is $1$ if $D>0$ and $0$ if $D<0$. This means that for every squarefree integer $D$ there is some finite abelian group $\mu_D$ such that
\begin{eqnarray*}
G_{\sqrt{D}}&\cong&\Bbb{Z}\times\mu_D\qquad&\text{ if }D>0,\\
G_{\sqrt{D}}&\cong&\mu_D,\qquad&\text{ if }D<0.
\end{eqnarray*}
It is a nice exercise to verify that the *torsion group* $\mu_D$ is $\langle-1\rangle$ if $D\neq-1,-3$. The two exceptional values $D=-1$ and $D=-3$ correspond to the Gaussian and Eisenstein integers, respectively, with torsion groups $\langle i\rangle$ and $\langle\omega\rangle$ that are cyclic of orders $4$ and $6$, respectively.

Comment: Ooo, it is not on sophomore level. I've struggled to find the generator. Thank you for answering! <3

Comment: There are more elementary ways to show the above, even at sophomore level, but it depends on your background. Finding an explicit generator for the free part is more difficult though. Deterministic algorithms exist, but there is no 'general formula'.