# A general formula for the solutions of the negative Pell's equation

Tags: number-theory, pell-type-equations

I want to find an explicit formula for the solutions of the negative Pell's equation
$x^2 - Dy^2 = -1$ in terms of {a, b} with $D = a^2 + b^2$

I already know that the nth solution is given by the formula $y_n = y_0F[2n+1, 2x_0]$ with {$x_0, y_0$} the fundamental solution and $F[m,k]$ the [Fibonacci polynomials](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FibonacciPolynomial.html).

Using the results I found [here](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/Ayoub-1-0745924.pdf) and [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/340006125_THE_NEGATIVE_PELL_EQUATION_AND_FIBONACCI_SEQUENCES):

if b = 1  the nth solution $y_n = F[2n+1, 2a]$  with n ∈ ℕ

if b = 2 the nth solution $y_n = 1/2 * F[3(2n+1), a]$ with n ∈ ℕ

I want to generalize the result for b = 3, 4,... but I'm stuck.

I tried to find a generating function of some kind, whose coefficients could let me express the nth solution  $y_n$ as a function of b: I just found that the nth odd coefficients of the generating function $ f[x]=y_0*x/(1/2 - x^2/2 - (x_0)x)$ represent the generic nth solution $y_n$.

While studying this problem, I discovered this identity too

$F[(2k+1)n, t] = F[2k+1, t]*F[n, L[2k+1, t]]$

with $L[m,k]$ the [Lucas polynomials](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LucasPolynomial.html), {k, n} ∈ ℕ  and t ∈ R

I guess it's a generalization of the identities you can find [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FibonacciPolynomial.html) using the Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4279913/solution-group-of-pells-equation

Answer (score 1):

ADDED  if you know integers such that $x^2 - D y^2 = -1,$  there is an extremely rapid way to construct $D = a^2 + b^2.$  This is reported in Stan Wagon (1990), Editor's Corner: The Euclidean Algorithm Strikes Again.  The exact value of $x$  is not explicitly used, you just need the representative $0 < t < D$   such that $x \equiv t  \pmod D,$  so that we still have $t^2 \equiv -1 \pmod D$

ORIGINAL you should be aware that there may be no solution.

$205 = 14^2 + 3^2=13^2+6^2,$  but there are no integer solutions to $ x^2 - 205 y^2 = -1$

$221 = 11^2 + 10^2= 14^2 +5^2,$  but there are no integer solutions to $ x^2 - 221 y^2 = -1$

with (positive) prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4,$  there are always solutions to $x^2 - p y^2 = -1$

with primes $p,q \equiv 1 \pmod 4,$   and Legendre symbols $(p|q)= (q|p) = -1,$ there are solutions to $x^2 - pq y^2 = -1$

However, when $(p|q)= (q|p) = 1,$ there need not be any solutions to $x^2 - pq y^2 = -1$  The examples above are $205=5 \cdot 41,$  where $5,41$  are mutual quadratic residues.   Next $221=13 \cdot 17,$  where $13,17$  are mutual quadratic residues.

The continued fraction of a number shows how to solve Pell's equation  as well as showing other numbers (of very small absolute value) that may be (primitively) represented as $x^2 - D y^2.$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$  \sqrt { 205} = 14 +     \frac{  \sqrt {205} - 14 }{ 1 }  $$
$$    \frac{ 1 }{   \sqrt {205} - 14 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {205} + 14 }{9 } = 3 +  \frac{    \sqrt {205} - 13 }{9 } $$
$$    \frac{ 9 }{   \sqrt {205} - 13 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {205} + 13 }{4 } = 6 +  \frac{    \sqrt {205} - 11 }{4 } $$
$$    \frac{ 4 }{   \sqrt {205} - 11 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {205} + 11 }{21 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {205} - 10 }{21 } $$
$$    \frac{ 21 }{   \sqrt {205} - 10 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {205} + 10 }{5 } = 4 +  \frac{    \sqrt {205} - 10 }{5 } $$
$$    \frac{ 5 }{   \sqrt {205} - 10 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {205} + 10 }{21 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {205} - 11 }{21 } $$
$$    \frac{ 21 }{   \sqrt {205} - 11 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {205} + 11 }{4 } = 6 +  \frac{    \sqrt {205} - 13 }{4 } $$
$$    \frac{ 4 }{   \sqrt {205} - 13 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {205} + 13 }{9 } = 3 +  \frac{    \sqrt {205} - 14 }{9 } $$
$$    \frac{ 9 }{   \sqrt {205} - 14 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {205} + 14 }{1 } = 28 +  \frac{    \sqrt {205} - 14 }{1 } $$

Simple continued fraction tableau:
$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccccc}
 & & 14 & & 3 & & 6 & & 1 & & 4 & & 1 & & 6 & & 3 & & 28 & \\ 
 \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 14 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 43 }{ 3 }   & &   \frac{ 272 }{ 19 }   & &   \frac{ 315 }{ 22 }   & &   \frac{ 1532 }{ 107 }   & &   \frac{ 1847 }{ 129 }   & &   \frac{ 12614 }{ 881 }   & &   \frac{ 39689 }{ 2772 }    \\ 
  \\ 
 & 1 & & -9 & & 4 & & -21 & & 5 & & -21 & & 4 & & -9 & & 1
 \end{array}
 $$

$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccc}
  \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & 1^2 - 205 \cdot 0^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  14  \\  
  \frac{ 14 }{ 1 }   & 14^2 - 205 \cdot 1^2 = -9 &     \mbox{digit}  &  3  \\  
  \frac{ 43 }{ 3 }   & 43^2 - 205 \cdot 3^2 = 4 &     \mbox{digit}  &  6  \\  
  \frac{ 272 }{ 19 }   & 272^2 - 205 \cdot 19^2 = -21 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 315 }{ 22 }   & 315^2 - 205 \cdot 22^2 = 5 &     \mbox{digit}  &  4  \\  
  \frac{ 1532 }{ 107 }   & 1532^2 - 205 \cdot 107^2 = -21 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 1847 }{ 129 }   & 1847^2 - 205 \cdot 129^2 = 4 &     \mbox{digit}  &  6  \\  
  \frac{ 12614 }{ 881 }   & 12614^2 - 205 \cdot 881^2 = -9 &     \mbox{digit}  &  3  \\  
  \frac{ 39689 }{ 2772 }   & 39689^2 - 205 \cdot 2772^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  28  \\  
 \end{array}
 $$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$  \sqrt { 221} = 14 +     \frac{  \sqrt {221} - 14 }{ 1 }  $$
$$    \frac{ 1 }{   \sqrt {221} - 14 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {221} + 14 }{25 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {221} - 11 }{25 } $$
$$    \frac{ 25 }{   \sqrt {221} - 11 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {221} + 11 }{4 } = 6 +  \frac{    \sqrt {221} - 13 }{4 } $$
$$    \frac{ 4 }{   \sqrt {221} - 13 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {221} + 13 }{13 } = 2 +  \frac{    \sqrt {221} - 13 }{13 } $$
$$    \frac{ 13 }{   \sqrt {221} - 13 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {221} + 13 }{4 } = 6 +  \frac{    \sqrt {221} - 11 }{4 } $$
$$    \frac{ 4 }{   \sqrt {221} - 11 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {221} + 11 }{25 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {221} - 14 }{25 } $$
$$    \frac{ 25 }{   \sqrt {221} - 14 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {221} + 14 }{1 } = 28 +  \frac{    \sqrt {221} - 14 }{1 } $$

Simple continued fraction tableau:
$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccc}
 & & 14 & & 1 & & 6 & & 2 & & 6 & & 1 & & 28 & \\ 
 \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 14 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 15 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 104 }{ 7 }   & &   \frac{ 223 }{ 15 }   & &   \frac{ 1442 }{ 97 }   & &   \frac{ 1665 }{ 112 }    \\ 
  \\ 
 & 1 & & -25 & & 4 & & -13 & & 4 & & -25 & & 1
 \end{array}
 $$

$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccc}
  \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & 1^2 - 221 \cdot 0^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  14  \\  
  \frac{ 14 }{ 1 }   & 14^2 - 221 \cdot 1^2 = -25 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 15 }{ 1 }   & 15^2 - 221 \cdot 1^2 = 4 &     \mbox{digit}  &  6  \\  
  \frac{ 104 }{ 7 }   & 104^2 - 221 \cdot 7^2 = -13 &     \mbox{digit}  &  2  \\  
  \frac{ 223 }{ 15 }   & 223^2 - 221 \cdot 15^2 = 4 &     \mbox{digit}  &  6  \\  
  \frac{ 1442 }{ 97 }   & 1442^2 - 221 \cdot 97^2 = -25 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 1665 }{ 112 }   & 1665^2 - 221 \cdot 112^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  28  \\  
 \end{array}
 $$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the late reply. What I'm trying to find is a compact form for the generic solution  when b = 3,4,5... I know from various theorems that for any resolvable NPE D is the sum of 2 squares, and I would like to find a relation between the solutions and both a and b. E.g. D = 58 = 7^2 + 3^2, so b = 3, but I can't find a solution in terms of Fibonacci polinomials like for the case b=1,2